# Is this a valid CSS font?

Tags: css

Folks! I am not an expert in CSS, I am currently trying to understand a codebase that has css file with following syntax

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Avenir LT";
 url(/Fonts/8afe744b-89a2-4ae2-a88e-05c6882580f3.svg#8afe744b-89a2-4ae2-a88e-05c6882580f3) format("svg")
}
```

I do not know if the `url` pattern is correct. Specifically, the part after `svg`. 
Can some one help me understand this?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely it's a fingerprint for cache-busting purposes

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.
See docs for the details, for example - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

It seems you missed `src` property, so your styles should look like

```
font-face {
 font-family: "Avenir LT";
 src: url(/Fonts/8afe744b-89a2-4ae2-a88e-05c6882580f3.svg#8afe744b-89a2-4ae2-a88e-05c6882580f3) format("svg");
}
```

Comment: Which bit of the docs are you referring to specifically. Also that page is in Russian.

Comment: My fault. Updated to page link to English one